# How to pass or display mySQL data based on subscription or billing

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce, subscription, billing

I want to build a PHP based site where, the user can view data based on the types of data they've paid for.

Allow me to use something simple for an example.

Let's say historical data for basketball was not readily available but could be purchased.
Simple information such as the Winner, Loser, Final score and date are all stored in a mySQL table.

What would be involved so that, when the user logs in, they can only see the historical data they have paid for.

My theories so far about the architecture:

I imagined a mySQL table storing True or False values for all historical game data they have paid for. Based on this, a 'data chart' object enables the user to view all data within their mySQL row which has a value of 'true.'

Follow ups:

Assuming I am correct, what methods are popular or practical for this type of service.

Comment: This sounds like homework... What about having different types of data available? For example, by team, or by season? I think the structure you would want has to start with a PaidEntity table that stores **who** paid for **what**. No?

Comment: Lol not homework at all. I'm just a noob.(Thanks for the reply!) Yes, assuming I have a table that says who paid for what...would I be able to pass data based on what's in that table?

I guess what I'm really trying to ask is:

Assuming a table records that users a c f paid for games 1 3 5, and another table holds all of the game information, is there a way to pass the information from games 1,3,5 using some type of key value or identity?

I apologize if what I'm describing sounds ignorant, it's because I'm very new to PHP and mySQL. I'm having the hardest time articulating what I'm thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we're going with the sporting paradigm...

Every game needs to have a unique ID. Then you have a table of customers, each also with a unique ID. Then you have a table that describes who paid for what. A table with two columns of ID's, customerID and gameID. This is what is called normalization.

So, in your joining table you might have CUSTOMER ID 001, who have paid for games 001, 003, and 005. Here is the customer table:

```
.------------------------------.
| customer_id | customer_name  |
|------------------------------|
| 001         | SPM, Inc.      |
| 002         | Stack Overflow |
'------------------------------'
```

Here is the game table:

```
.---------------------------------.
| game_id     | description       |
|---------------------------------|
| 001         | Giants v. Red Sox |      |
| 002         | Blah v. Yada      |
| 003         | Vader v. Kenobi   |
| 004         | Romney v. Obama   |
| 005         | Roth v. Hagar     |
'---------------------------------'
```

Here is the table that corresponds to who paid for what:

```
.-----------------------------.
| customer_id | game_id       |
|-----------------------------|
| 001         | 001           |
| 001         | 003           |
| 001         | 005           |
| 002         | 002           |
| 002         | 005           |
'-----------------------------'
```

Notice how the ID's in the last table are not unique.

Comment: Dude...you are f$(*ing awesome. Thank you for this, seriously. I guess my only other speculation here is, I assume that if a customer pays for new data, that information could be passed on to the third table once the payment is complete. Would I be correct in that? Thanks again, no one has taken the time to answer this question for me.

Comment: Looking at it, the model is straight forward. I guess what I was really trying to ask is, is there a way to call information within a row using a key value/id, which you have shown here. I feel slightly inept.

Comment: You'll get there. It's pretty straightforward when you get used to it. Because the actual paid data is outside of the customer/game data you can add or delete at will. You could even add a DATE column to use in a subscription type situation. The possibilities are endless. At the end of the day, I would definitely recommend getting a good book and just working through examples.

Comment: Ian, one last question for you. Let's say I had a year of historical data for every team in the MLB. Would you suggest multiple databases with one for each team? Or one database with multiple tables?

Comment: All in one database for sure. Joining databases is totally unnecessary.